# How to close windows service application through coding

Tags: c#, windows-services

I asked this yesterday but I didn't got an answer, the community closed it and down voted it, gave a cynical comments with no serious answer, so I deleted the previous question.

I developed a windows service app in C#

My question: How to close windows service application through coding.

```
        //here is the stop button
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
          //some code here that close the app
           //how to close??????????????
        }
```

In Windows forms it's: `Application.Exit();`

I am asking that because the app still running in the background even after I stopped it.

please serious answers only.

Comment: I'm sorry your question does not make sense. A service is *supposed* to run in the background. And does not have a UI or "button". It's also not normally called an "app". Do you want to stop your service? Programatically? Why not show some code then, maybe a [MCVE].

Comment: @nvoigt you *can* stop/start the app via task manager

Comment: @Error404 That is called a process

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in that linked duplicate. I have read your other recent questions and you seem to be in over your head. I think it would be a good idea to take a step back and read a good book or tutorial on this cover-to-cover. This stuff (including asking questions about it) is way easier when you have some basics and know the vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

I do as below for closing my windows service ..

1.Created file with following command , file name is "StopServiceInstances.cmd"

```
   net stop <service name>
```

2.and called file by below line of code , by setting system.timer(this get called at specific time) which used for closing service

```
   var process = Process.Start
          (ApplicationExecutionPath+ "\\StopServiceInstances.cmd");
```

if you dont want to code for timer than you can also make use of `Task Scheduler` program available in windows operating system. In this you can set time and also set which program you want to call.

[image]

Comment: What code should I write inside the `onStop` button?

Comment: @Error404 - as suggested creaet file called  "StopServiceInstances.cmd" and in that file write this  net stop <service name> ....than on onstop button you have to call this file that you can do with var process = Process.Start
          (ApplicationExecutionPath+ "\\StopServiceInstances.cmd"); ..here Execution path is path you are executing , assembly exeuction path or hardcode path of file